# Vue-type failed to resolve component in nuxt3

Tags: css, vue.js, animation, nuxt.js

To apply some fancy animation to text, I'm trying to use vue-typer in a nuxt3 project.
Then I installed the package with:

`npm install --save vue-typer`

So I simply use the component in a template with some sample text:

`<vue-typer text='Hello World! I was registered locally!'></vue-typer>`

Nothing appears on the screen, and not even in the DOM.
In fact, the log contains:
`[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: vue-typer 22:17:26 If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.`

Then, I tried to add an import in my script tag:

`import VueTyper from "vue-typer"`

But now there is an error "document is not defined" and the server doesn't work.

What can I try to make it work?

Comment: Did you import `vue-typer` component? Please add minimal the code of your component where you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to import it, simply with:
`import VueTyper from "vue-typer"`

Comment: Did someone solve this? I have the same problem.